# How do i beautify the output in json?

Tags: arrays, json, go, code-formatting

So I wrote this really simple go app and all it does it show a bunch of info in JSON but all the output data is minified and I need some help beautifying all the data.

```
func ExampleHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
        "accept":                    r.Header.Get("Accept"),
    })
    w.Write(resp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`resp, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{...})`

to

`resp, _ := json.MarshalIndent(map[string]string{...}, "", "  ")`

See [`json.MarshalIndent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent)

Comment: A+ Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

Use `json.Indent`:

```
resp, _ := json.Marshal(...)
dst := bytes.Buffer{}
json.Indent(&dst,resp,"","  ")
w.Write(dsr.Bytes())
```

Comment: hey i am very new to go can I get a bit more help please.

Comment: What is unclear in the answer? Look at the documentation for `json.Indent`, or describe what you need.